# What does Mockito.mock do and suggestions why this implementation won´t work when getting rid of Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I have the following interface `CatalogVersionService` which exposes some services. As well I have a unit test which mocks this interface by using Mockito like this:

```
CatalogVersionService catalogVersionService  = Mockito.mock(CatalogVersionService.class);
```

And injects the `catalogVersionService`  in a resolver implementation named `DefaultClassificationClassResolverService` like this:

```
((DefaultClassificationClassResolverService) ccrservice).setCatalogVersionService(catalogVersionService);

// Assert that my resolver will find a single ClassificationClassModel object
ClassificationClassModel single = new ClassificationClassModel();
        assertTrue(ccrservice.resolve(single).contains(single)); //resolver
```

Up to that point everything works fine until I try to create an integration test and get rid of the Mocked `CatalogVersionService` interface.  As far as I am aware `Mockito.mock` creates a mock object of given class or interface, in this case `CatalogVersionService` which is implemented by `DefaultCatalogVersionService`. So when I try to obtain the real object I do something like this:

```
catalogVersionService = new DefaultCatalogVersionService();
((DefaultClassificationClassResolverService) ccrservice).setCatalogVersionService(catalogVersionService);
```

However, after that point is where I get a null pointer exception and my resolver test of course fails. So what does Mockito.mock actually do?? Is it a good approach to assume:

```
CatalogVersionService catalogVersionService  = Mockito.mock(CatalogVersionService.class);
// IS EQUIVALENT TO:
catalogVersionService = new DefaultCatalogVersionService();
```

Any ideas why the assert is failing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is incorrect to assume that `Mockito.mock(...)` is the same as instantiating an instance of your `DefaultCatalogVersionService`. This is not what mocks do.

If you are getting a NullPointerException when using the concrete `DefaultCatalogVersionService`, this would suggest that *something is null within the `DefaultCatalogVersionService`*!

Have you examined the stacktrace to see at what line the NullPointerException occurs, which would help you determine which property/field is null?

It's more than likely that your `DefaultCatalogVersionService` depends on other classes, which you are not wiring up in your test.

Comment: thanks @matt b for your reply but then how does Mockito.mock(CatalogVersionService.class); wires everything up?

Comment: It doesn't. It creates a dynamic mock object that implements the CatalogVersionService interface, but it does not know how to response to method calls on it's own. To tell Mockito what to do when CatalogVersionService.doSomething() is called, you use `when(mock.doSomething()).thenReturn(..)`, and to verify that the class using `CatalogVersionService` called the methods you expect it to, you use `verify(mock).something()`. Take a look at the [mockito documentation](http://mockito.org/).

Comment: However, Mockito has nothing to do with why you are getting a NPE when using the real class. That is likely because the default implementation depends on other objects which you have not instantiated. With Mockito, you don't notice when methods are called without any behavior definitions because the mocked methods "do nothing" by default.

Comment: Hey @matt b unfortunately I cant vote you up cause I dont have enough reputation but. Now it is working, I did not have my DefaultCatalogVersionService properly wired up on the spring configuration file as you said. Thanks for the useful information I appreciate your help great job!